# Get the IP Address of the RDP Client using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ip-address, rdp

I'm trying to get the IP address of the RDP client so we can keep record of everyone who is connecting to our server and at what times. Is there a way to do this using VB.net? Everything I've tried just returns the IP address of the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have anymore information on your RDP connection settings or logging or anything? I would try to answer your question but I do not have enough information on your RDP settings to do so. For instance, is the RDP client connecting over VPN or local? This makes a big difference.

Comment: Currently the RDP is running on a local network but in time will be rolled out to external clients. The RDP when it loads it only loads Internet Explorer not the whole desktop

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from the [**actual code**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/857af1fe-75a4-4845-b989-f18636f296c9/using-visual-basic-net-to-access-terminal-services-session-and-client-information) what you are looking for.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim serverName As String
        Dim clientInfo As New WTS_CLIENT_INFO
        ReDim clientInfo.Address(20)
        serverName = ""
        'Server Name can be name of choice or name of server on which this application is running
        If GetSessions(serverName, clientInfo) = True Then
            Dim str As String
            str = "User Name: " & clientInfo.WTSUserName
            str &= vbNewLine & "Station Name: " & clientInfo.WTSStationName
            str &= vbNewLine & "Domain Name: " & clientInfo.WTSDomainName
            If clientInfo.WTSStationName <> "Console" Then
                str &= vbNewLine & "Client Name: " & clientInfo.WTSClientName
                str &= vbNewLine & "Client IP: " & clientInfo.Address(2) & "." & clientInfo.Address(3) & "." & clientInfo.Address(4) & "." & clientInfo.Address(5)
            End If
            MessageBox.Show(str)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your solution and it runs but it gives me a IP address that is in Japan somewhere, when I refresh the page it gives me a completely different IP address

Comment: you want to know the IP Address only? why dont you post a http call then obtain the response in string (parse) it lastly... as you're requested....